# implementation of react redux with an IIS API

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'am trying to use react-redux to retrieve data from an ISS API.
I have to retrieve several lists (a list of items, a list of types of items, ...)
I need the list of types of items to create a dropdown list.
When I retrieve the list of items, everything is ok. When I render the detail of an item, it's also ok but if I try to add my list of types of items, I've got network errors.
I think I've made mistakes in the implementation of redux but I can't find where.
I have several reducers combined into a root reducer.
I'd like to know if its right to declare a const initialState = [] in each reducer
eg :
articlesReducer.js

```
const initialState = []
function articleReducer(articles = initialState, action){
 const {type, payload } = action
 switch(type){
  ...
  case RETRIEVE items:
      return payload
...
```

Same principle for other lists.

I don't know if I have given enough information.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Why do you think a network error is related to redux implementation?

Comment: Because, I first receive the list of items.  If I want to render the detail without the list of types, everythink is OK but if I add my dropdown list, the first time, it's OK but if I go to the general list of items again, after two or three times, the network error appears.  One of my colleague has checked the IIS server and he tells me the error comes from my side.  As I am new with react and redux, I'm not sure of what I've made

Comment: do you mind sharing the error and the actions that make the requests?

Comment: I'll take some print screens

Comment: I don't know how to add the screenshots

Comment: I've add some screenshots in my post

Comment: I retrieve the data each time I go to the articleList page ?  Is it normal.  I'd like to retrieve the data only when I initialize the application but I don't know how to do it